# Do the index number and size information of array in crash report remain same as original code?

Tags: java, android, debugging, proguard

In my android app I am using following proguard rules.

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

Following is bug report summary and it does not mention the proper line number and class name. Are the Index number and size mentioned in this report supposed to be same as original or are they changed?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 10
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
at c.b.a.F.b(SourceFile:21)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$a.a(SourceFile:14)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(SourceFile:157)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$c.a(SourceFile:10)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(SourceFile:108)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(SourceFile:95)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.e(SourceFile:119)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.f(SourceFile:8)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.d(SourceFile:9)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(SourceFile:2)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:12)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:757)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20710)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2366)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1505)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7353)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1100)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:895)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:826)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1086)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception was removed after removing the call to 11th index of array.So the answer to original question would be yes, the index number and size information of array in crash report remain same as original code.